# Load text file from specific location objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, load, nsfilemanager

I was wondering how to read a file from a specific location on ios.

For example I'd quite like to have files of the same name stored in different locations for example.

Project/Files/Text/1.txt

Project/Files/MoreText/1.txt

At the moment I can load files in but I can't see how to specify a specific directory. My program seems to load a file in regardless of where it is meaning I can only have one text file or the other working.

I have tried using NSFileManager:

```
NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *filelist = [filemanager directoryContentsAtPath:@"Text"];
```

but I later realised that this actually isn't doing anything. It just returns no objects. I've also seen NSBundle but haven't seen an example where a specific file is returned.

I need the filenames to be the same for my algorithm which loads the files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to read files from the app bundle and you want a certain directory structure, then you need to create a directory in Finder. Then create the directory structure you want in the main directory you just made. Now add the files to the appropriate folders and then add the main directory to your project by dragging it in to Xcode.

Here is the code to read from the main bundle:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Text/1" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

This will read the file "1.txt" from the directory "Text".

Answer (score 2):

iOS application will save all file to root directory, a Group(yellow icon) not a real directory. If you want put your resources into a sub directory, can using this following steps:

1. Create a directory in the Finder, put your files into this directory.
2. In Xcode, select "Add Files to..." from File menu.
3. Select "Copy items into destination group's folder" and "Create Folder References for any added folders" in the popup.

Then, you will found a blue icon directory in your project, It is a real directory.

Now, you can read the files use NSBundle Class method:

```
+ (NSArray *)pathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)bundlePath
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested, I put the files in a separate folder in my project but when I add the files and do as you suggest it seems to make a copy of them in the base directory rather then use the files in the folder. What's going wrong?

Comment: I should also say I'm using xCode 3 rather than 4.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, keep in mind that by default all files goes to 1 directory after compiling. To put them to directory you have to specify that in xCode. As for loading goes you can just enter relative path "MyDir/myFile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths don't work on Mac OS X--this is because the current directory is ignored by Cocoa, and changes pretty nearly at random. You need to always work with an absolute path. To get the absolute path to your app's `Resources` directory, use:

```
NSString *resDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

Then to enumerate the contents of the `Text` directory in that directory:

```
NSString *textDir = [resDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Text"];
NSArray *textFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: textDir];
```

However, Xcode may or may not honour the file hierarchy in your app's `Resources` directory. To determine if files are where you expect them to be, you should build your app, right-click the `.app` bundle, and select `Show Package Contents`.